# Function return type and pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having some trouble with function return types and pointers (sorry if this a stupid question but haven't programmed C in quite some time). When I to run this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

char *parse(char const *data) {
    return data;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *a = "# Test";
    char newString = parse(a);
    printf("%s\n", &newString);
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error:

```
writer.c: In function ‘parse’: writer.c:6: warning: return from incompatible pointer type 
writer.c:6: warning: function returns address of local variable writer.c: In function ‘main’: 
writer.c:11: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse(a)` returns `char*`, and newString is type of `char` so they are incompatible.

Change this:

```
char newString = parse(a);
printf("%s\n", &newString);
```

to this:

```
char *newString = parse(a);
printf("%s\n", newString);
```

Regarding your errors / warnings:

> writer.c: In function ‘parse’:
>   writer.c:6: warning: return from
>   incompatible pointer type

You return `const char*` while your function return type is `char*`

> writer.c:6: warning: function returns
>   address of local variable writer.c: In
>   function

data is considered a local variable and you return this address, which might be dangerous if it was defined inside the function.

> ‘main’:  writer.c:11: warning:
>   initialization makes integer from
>   pointer without a cast

You assign `char*` to a `char`.

And as a side note: when you use a char pointer to a constant string, make it const: `const char *a = "# Test";`

Comment: thanks! but I still get an error: `writer.c: In function ‘parse’:
writer.c:6: warning: return discards qualifiers from pointer target type`

Comment: see edit. I think you'll find it helpful, also, a warning is not an error, but it's great that you treat it as such :)

Comment: thanks, I never like to have any warnings, sometimes I speed longer fixing warnings than errors!